# Replacing NaNs with Mean Value using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a Dataframe called `Data` with shape `(71067, 4)`:

```
       StartTime          EndDateTime        TradeDate  Values
0   2018-12-31 23:00:00 2018-12-31 23:30:00 2019-01-01  -44.676
1   2018-12-31 23:30:00 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01  -36.113
2   2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 00:30:00 2019-01-01  -19.229
3   2019-01-01 00:30:00 2019-01-01 01:00:00 2019-01-01  -23.606
4   2019-01-01 01:00:00 2019-01-01 01:30:00 2019-01-01  -25.899
... ... ... ... ...
    2023-01-30 20:30:00 2023-01-30 21:00:00 2023-01-30  -27.198
    2023-01-30 21:00:00 2023-01-30 21:30:00 2023-01-30  -13.221
    2023-01-30 21:30:00 2023-01-30 22:00:00 2023-01-30  -12.034
    2023-01-30 22:00:00 2023-01-30 22:30:00 2023-01-30  -16.464
    2023-01-30 22:30:00 2023-01-30 23:00:00 2023-01-30  -25.441
71067 rows × 4 columns
```

When running `Data.isna().sum().sum()` I realise I have some NaN values in the dataset:

```
Data.isna().sum().sum()
> 1391
```

Shown here:

```
Data[Data['Values'].isna()].reset_index(drop = True).sort_values(by = 'StartTime')

0   2019-01-01 03:30:00 2019-01-01 04:00:00 2019-01-01  NaN
1   2019-01-04 02:30:00 2019-01-04 03:00:00 2019-01-04  NaN
2   2019-01-04 03:00:00 2019-01-04 03:30:00 2019-01-04  NaN
3   2019-01-04 03:30:00 2019-01-04 04:00:00 2019-01-04  NaN
4   2019-01-04 04:00:00 2019-01-04 04:30:00 2019-01-04  NaN
... ... ... ... ...
1386    2022-12-06 13:00:00 2022-12-06 13:30:00 2022-12-06  NaN
1387    2022-12-06 13:30:00 2022-12-06 14:00:00 2022-12-06  NaN
1388    2022-12-22 11:00:00 2022-12-22 11:30:00 2022-12-22  NaN
1389    2023-01-25 11:00:00 2023-01-25 11:30:00 2023-01-25  NaN
1390    2023-01-25 11:30:00 2023-01-25 12:00:00 2023-01-25  NaN
```

Is there anyway of replacing each of the NaN values in the dataset with the mean value of the corresponding half hour across the 70,000 plus rows, see below:

```
Data['HH'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['StartTime']).dt.time
Data.groupby(['HH'], as_index=False)[['Data']].mean().head(10)
# Only showing first 10 means

    HH          Values
0   00:00:00    5.236811
1   00:30:00    2.056571
2   01:00:00    4.157455
3   01:30:00    2.339253
4   02:00:00    2.658238
5   02:30:00    0.230557
6   03:00:00    0.217599
7   03:30:00    -0.630243
8   04:00:00    -0.989919
9   04:30:00    -0.494372
```

For example, if a value is missing against 04:00, can it be replaced with the 04:00 mean value `(0.989919)` as per the above table of means?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's group the dataframe by `HH` then transform the `Values` with `mean` to broadcast the mean values back to the original column shape then use `fillna` to fill the null values

```
avg = Data.groupby('HH')['Values'].transform('mean')
Data['Values'] = Data['Values'].fillna(avg)
```